# Is it possible to target iOS 7 with Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am building an app in Xamarin forms (using Xamaring 4.4.0.34) that will target iPhone/iPad and Android (and maybe later UWP). I've have been testing mostly in android as it was convenient but have recently begun my iOS testing. App works great on my test iPad Air 1 but crashes right after start-up on my iPhone 4S. Figured out that it crashes because a call is made to a UIScrollView method that was introduced in iOS 8.

Fair enough - but is there a way to target earlier iOS versions (7) with Xamarin forms? If not, I guess I'll have to state the minimum supported version for my app is iOS 8 but if there is some magical way I could support earlier versions, then great.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Forms [requires](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/installation/#Target_Platforms) iOS 8 or better

> Xamarin.Forms applications can be written for the following operating
>   systems:
>
> - iOS 8 or higher
> - Android 4.0.3 (API 15) or higher (more details)
> - Windows 10 Universal Windows Platform (more details)
> - Windows 8.1 /
> - Windows Phone 8.1 WinRT (more details)
> - Windows Phone 8 Silverlight
>     (DEPRECATED)

Comment: Thanks. There were some conflicting answers found around the internet so I was uncertain - they were probably all related to a previous version of Forms.